# how to punctuate that that in a sentence

Tags: punctuation

Should you use a comma between the two "that that's" in a sentence as in "that that might be a consideration" or not?

Comment: Except in rare circumstances, simply remove a *that*.

Comment: Generally, you can use "that that" without a comma or replace the combination with "what."  "What is wrong is wrong."  "That that is wrong is wrong."  Neither is grammatically improper.

Comment: What rule would lead you to insert a comma?

Comment: _that that might be a consideration_ seems more like a fragment than a sentence. This question could be improved with a better example.

Answer (score 0):

*That* introduces a restrictive clause, which includes information vital to the sentence, so you don't need a comma for it.

(Source: *The Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation*.)